# Kafka Tool Unable to connect broker 1

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I opened 1 zookeeper and 3 kafka nodes on docker with configuration below.

I opened console producer and consumer.

I created topic, sent and received message in reqular way.

Kafka Tool connects the kafka cluster on docker, and read the brokers and port numbers but not read the topics and consumers.

When I clicked on topics " Unable to connect broker 1" message is shown.

How can I fix this problem, any contribution will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Docker Compose yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
        - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka2
    ports:
        - "9095:9095"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9095
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9095
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka3
    ports:
        - "9096:9096"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka3:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9096
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka3:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9096
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
```

I read and configure the listener config on docker compose.